# I'm getting empty values when parsing Microdata

Tags: java, jsoup, microdata

```html
 <div class="content-sidebar-wrap"><main class="content" role="main" itemprop="mainContentOfPage" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog"><article class="post-2334 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail category-blog-basics entry" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" itemprop="blogPost"><header class="entry-header"><h1 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">Examples of Blogs</h1> 
    <p class="entry-meta">by <span class="entry-author" itemprop="author" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span class="entry-author-name" itemprop="name">Kenneth Byrd</span></span> | Go from 0 to 5,000 blog subscribers in 60 days <a href="https://curlcentric.leadpages.net/leadbox/14581e773f72a2%3A12e927026b46dc/5758142528880640/" rel="nofollow">(Click Here)</a></p></header><img src="http://blogbasics.com/wp-content/uploads/Examples-of-Blogs.jpg" width="5315" height="3543" alt="examples of blogs" title="" class="attachment-tru-post wp-post-image" /><div class="entry-content" itemprop="text"><h3>Overview</h3>
    <p>This article includes examples of blogs from various niches. There are millions of example blogs out there in all different shapes and sizes. A good place to start is <a href="http://technorati.com/" target="_blank">Technorati</a>, a directory of blogs, or <a href="http://alltop.com/" target="_blank">Alltop</a>. Search these websites and then come back and tell us about the good blogs and the bad blogs that you found. Below are also more examples of blogs that you should look at:</p>
    <h3><strong>Personal blogs</strong></h3>
    <p><a title="Curl Centric" href="http://www.curlcentric.com/natural-hair-101/" target="_blank">Curl Centric</a>: Dedicated to providing healthy hair care information.</p>
    <h3>Travel</h3>
    <p><a href="http://boardingarea.com/" target="_blank">Boarding Area</a>:  A collection of bloggers on travel.  Range from personal stories to specific advice on airlines, hotels and places.</p>
    <div class="content-box-yellow"><a href="https://curlcentric.leadpages.net/leadbox/14581e773f72a2%3A12e927026b46dc/5758142528880640/">Learn how to start a blog that generates traffic, revenue, &amp; popularity.</a></div>
    <p><a href="http://vivisrandomramblings.blogspot.com/" target="_blank">Vivi&#8217;s Random Ramblings</a>: A nice collection of random posts mostly demonstrating that Violy is a well-travelled, excellent photographer.</p>
    <!-- Quick Adsense WordPress Plugin: http://quicksense.net/ -->
    <div style="float:none;margin:5px 0 5px 0;text-align:center;">
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- Blog Basics - 300 x 250 -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-5556427932737077"
         data-ad-slot="6553509385"></ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
    </div>
```

I am trying to parse the values of all `itemprop` which is present inside of all `itemtype` attributes in HTML source code using Jsoup library.

Here is the sample HTML page body:

```html
<body class="single single-post postid-2334 single-format-standard custom-header header-image header-full-width full-width-content" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage"><div class="site-container"><header class="site-header" role="banner" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader"><div class="wrap"><div class="title-area"><p class="site-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="http://blogbasics.com/">Blog Basics</a></p><div id="title_image"><a href="http://blogbasics.com/" title="Blog Basics"><img src="http://blogbasics.com/wp-content/uploads/cropped-cropped-Win-1.png" title="Blog Basics" /></a><style>#title { display:none; }</style></div><p class="site-description" itemprop="description">Starting a blog? Learn how to make it amazing.</p></div></div></header><nav class="nav-primary" role="navigation" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement"><div class="wrap"><ul id="menu-primary-navigation" class="menu genesis-nav-menu menu-primary"><li id="menu-item-2590" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-2590"><a title="Blog Basics" href="http://blogbasics.com">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-3187" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-3187"><a href="http://blogbasics.com/blog">Blog</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-3722" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-3722"><a href="http://blogbasics.com/welcome">Free Updates</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-2578" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2578"><a title="Blogging Tools" href="http://blogbasics.com/blogging-tools/">Blogging Tools</a></li>
</ul></div></nav><div class="site-inner"><div class="feature-area widget-area">
<div id="spyr_tru_notifybar-2" class="widget notify_bar"><div class="widget-wrap">Starting a blog? Learn how to make it awesome!</div></div>

<div id="spyr_tru_twocolumn-3" class="widget widget_spyr_tru_twocolumn"><div class="widget-wrap">
<div class="column one-half first original"><div align="middle"><a href="https://curlcentric.leadpages.net/leadbox/14581e773f72a2%3A12e927026b46dc/5758142528880640/" target="_blank"><img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/wMcDasimpny0oKmsIxI0xowRIxbFpaa9Rjg3aAUMG8UUtp4XamG03gYcGlsXTRmvkFqgySaihhq2_KCSr8cN7Q=s0"></a><script data-leadbox="14581e773f72a2:12e927026b46dc" data-url="https://curlcentric.leadpages.net/leadbox/14581e773f72a2%3A12e927026b46dc/5758142528880640/" data-config="%7B%7D" type="text/javascript" src="https://curlcentric.leadpages.net/leadbox-910.js"></script></div>
</div>
<div class="column one-half last original"><p>Learn how to build a blog that generates traffic, revenue, & popularity in 30 days.</p>
<p>Just enter your email address in the box below and click "Submit".</p>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div></div>
<div id="spyr_tru_subscribesocial-2" class="widget feature-area-bottom tru_subscribe_social"><div class="widget-wrap">
<div class="tru_subscribesocial_wrap">
    <form action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl" method="post" target="_blank">
        <div class="hidden_fields"><input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="276964962" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_split_id" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="listname" value="awlist3567293" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.aweber.com/thankyou-coi.htm?m=text" id="redirect_f956eccce03104dc62dec5f8c897285e" />

<input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="Blog_Basics" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_required" value="email" />

<input type="hidden" name="meta_tooltip" value="" /></div>
        <input type="email" class="default_value" name="email" value="Enter email to get updates" /></span>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    <div class="social_menu">
        <ul id="menu-social" class="menu superfish">

            </ul>
        </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div></div>
</div><div class="content-sidebar-wrap"><main class="content" role="main" itemprop="mainContentOfPage" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog"><article class="post-2334 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail category-blog-basics entry" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" itemprop="blogPost"><header class="entry-header"><h1 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">Examples of Blogs</h1> 
<p class="entry-meta">by <span class="entry-author" itemprop="author" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span class="entry-author-name" itemprop="name">Kenneth Byrd</span></span> | Go from 0 to 5,000 blog subscribers in 60 days <a href="https://curlcentric.leadpages.net/leadbox/14581e773f72a2%3A12e927026b46dc/5758142528880640/" rel="nofollow">(Click Here)</a></p></header><img src="http://blogbasics.com/wp-content/uploads/Examples-of-Blogs.jpg" width="5315" height="3543" alt="examples of blogs" title="" class="attachment-tru-post wp-post-image" /><div class="entry-content" itemprop="text"><h3>Overview</h3>
<p>This article includes examples of blogs from various niches. There are millions of example blogs out there in all different shapes and sizes. A good place to start is <a href="http://technorati.com/" target="_blank">Technorati</a>, a directory of blogs, or <a href="http://alltop.com/" target="_blank">Alltop</a>. Search these websites and then come back and tell us aboutÂ the good blogsÂ and the bad blogs that you found. Below are also more examples of blogs that you should look at:</p>
<h3><strong>Personal blogs</strong></h3>
<p><a title="Curl Centric" href="http://www.curlcentric.com/natural-hair-101/" target="_blank">Curl Centric</a>: Dedicated to providing healthy hair care information.</p>
<h3>Travel</h3>
<p><a href="http://boardingarea.com/" target="_blank">Boarding Area</a>: Â A collection of bloggers on travel. Â Range from personal stories to specific advice on airlines, hotels and places.</p>
<div class="content-box-yellow"><a href="https://curlcentric.leadpages.net/leadbox/14581e773f72a2%3A12e927026b46dc/5758142528880640/">Learn how to start a blog that generates traffic, revenue, &amp; popularity.</a></div>
<p><a href="http://vivisrandomramblings.blogspot.com/" target="_blank">Vivi&#8217;s Random Ramblings</a>: A nice collection of random posts mostly demonstrating that Violy is a well-travelled, excellent photographer.</p>
<!-- Quick Adsense WordPress Plugin: http://quicksense.net/ -->
<div style="float:none;margin:5px 0 5px 0;text-align:center;">
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Blog Basics - 300 x 250 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-5556427932737077"
     data-ad-slot="6553509385"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>

<p><a href="http://www.whygo.com/" target="_blank">Why go network of blogs</a>: Another group of travel bloggers. Â Each blogger has their own patch, which range from Portland, which looks a nice city, to Iceland and France.</p>
<h3>Technical</h3>
<p><a href="http://techcrunch.com/" target="_blank">Techcrunch</a>: Â This is the one to learn all about technology and in particular technology business, technology start-ups and gadgets. Â You&#8217;ll usually hear the techie gossip here first.</p>
<p><a href="http://speckyboy.com/2010/02/25/50-amazing-personal-blog-web-designs/" target="_blank">Speckyboy.com</a>: Great blog on the design of websites. Â Good on lists, (usually 50) of well researched examples of good or unusual design. Â Gives even the least technical good ideas to discuss with their own designers.</p>
<h3>On Blogging</h3>
<p><a href="http://www.trafficgenerationcafe.com/" target="_blank">Traffic Generation Cafe</a>: Ana Hoffman&#8217;s very friendly, very knowledgeable blog on building traffic for your blog.</p>
<div class="content-box-yellow"><a href="https://curlcentric.leadpages.net/leadbox/14581e773f72a2%3A12e927026b46dc/5758142528880640/">Learn how to start a blog that generates traffic, revenue, &amp; popularity.</a></div>
<p><a href="http://blogbasics.com/blog/" target="_blank">Blog Basics</a>: This website is a blog that is focused onÂ topics like &#8216;how to blog&#8217; and &#8216;how to make money blogging&#8217;.</p>
<h3>Over to you</h3>
<p>Which blogs do you like? Â Are you writing a blog? Â Then tell us about it.</p>

<!-- Quick Adsense WordPress Plugin: http://quicksense.net/ -->
<div style="float:none;margin:5px 0 5px 0;text-align:center;">
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Banner -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:468px;height:60px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-5556427932737077"
     data-ad-slot="1983708988"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>

<div style="font-size:0px;height:0px;line-height:0px;margin:0;padding:0;clear:both"></div><div style="clear:both;"></div><div id='ois-1' class='ois-design' ><div class="ois-outer ois-8-outer">
    <div class="ois-8-call-top"></div>
    <div class="ois-8-inner ois-inner">
        <div class="col-md-7 ois-8-left">
            <div class="ois-8-title">Get Exclusive Tips</div>
            <div class="ois-8-subtitle">Instantly discover how you can start a blog that generates traffic and income when you join the Blog Basics Tribe (Itâ€™s Free). Here's your chance. Just type in your email address.</div>
        </div> <!-- .span7 left side -->    
        <div class="col-md-5 ois-8-right">
            <div class="ois-8-img-wrapper">
                <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" data-src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/wMcDasimpny0oKmsIxI0xowRIxbFpaa9Rjg3aAUMG8UUtp4XamG03gYcGlsXTRmvkFqgySaihhq2_KCSr8cN7Q=s0" class="ois-img ois-8-img" /><noscript><img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/wMcDasimpny0oKmsIxI0xowRIxbFpaa9Rjg3aAUMG8UUtp4XamG03gYcGlsXTRmvkFqgySaihhq2_KCSr8cN7Q=s0" class="ois-img ois-8-img" /></noscript>
            </div>
            <div class="ois-8-form">
                <form action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl" method="post" id="ois-form-1" data-service="aweber" ><div id="ois-8-email-input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="email" class="ois-8-email-input ois-email-input ois-form-control" placeholder="Your Email"/>
</div>
<div id="ois-8-button-wrapper">
    <input type="submit" class="ois-btn ois-8-button" value="Submit"/>
</div><input type='hidden' name='listname' value='awlist3567293'/>
<input type='hidden' name='meta_message' value='1'/>
<input type='hidden' name='redirect' value='http://www.aweber.com/thankyou-coi.htm?m=video&e=example%40example.com&name=Example%20Subscriber&l=awlist3567293'/>
</form>
            </div> <!-- #ois-8-form -->
        </div><!-- .right .col-md-5 right side-->
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div> <!-- inner -->
</div> <!-- outer --></div></div>
<div class="spyr_sliding_share">
    <div class="spyr_sliding_share_text">Share this article</div>
    <div class="spyr_sliding_share_wrap">
            <div class="spyr_sliding_share_button spyr_sb_facebook">
                <a href="#" class="icon icon-facebook"><span>Facebook</span></a>
                <div class="spyr_sb_inner"><div class="fb-like" data-href="http://blogbasics.com/examples-of-blogs/" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false"></div></div>
                </div>
            <div class="spyr_sliding_share_button spyr_sb_twitter">
                <a href="#" class="icon icon-twitter"><span>Twitter</span></a>
                <div class="spyr_sb_inner"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://blogbasics.com/examples-of-blogs/" data-text="Examples of Blogs | Blog Basics" data-via="kbyrdjr">Tweet</a></div>
                </div>
            <div class="spyr_sliding_share_button spyr_sb_gplus">
                <a href="#" class="icon icon-gplus"><span>Google+</span></a>
                <div class="spyr_sb_inner"><div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-href="http://blogbasics.com/examples-of-blogs/"></div></div>
                </div>
            <div class="spyr_sliding_share_button spyr_sb_pinterest">
                <a href="#" class="icon icon-pinterest"><span>Pinterest</span></a>
                <div class="spyr_sb_inner"><a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://blogbasics.com/examples-of-blogs/&media=http://blogbasics.com/wp-content/uploads/Examples-of-Blogs-550x367.jpg&description=Examples of Blogs" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal"><img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" /></a></div>
                </div>
            <div class="spyr_sliding_share_button spyr_sb_mail">
                <a href="#" class="icon icon-mail"><span>Email a Friend</span></a>
                <div class="spyr_sb_inner"><a href="mailto:?subject=Examples of Blogs&body=I found value in this and I think you will too.%0A%0AExamples of Blogs: http://blogbasics.com/examples-of-blogs/">Email a Friend</a></div>
                </div>
        </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div><footer class="entry-footer"></footer></article><div class="entry-comments" id="comments"><h3>Comments</h3><ol class="comment-list">
    <li class="comment even thread-even depth-1" id="comment-261">
    <article itemprop="comment" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/UserComments">


        <header class="comment-header">
            <p class="comment-author" itemprop="creator" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
                <img alt='' src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" data-src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/9e0fce9a7b5f7de7f6c528f448007f08?s=48&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g" srcset='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/9e0fce9a7b5f7de7f6c528f448007f08?s=96&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-48 photo' height='48' width='48' /><noscript><img alt='' src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/9e0fce9a7b5f7de7f6c528f448007f08?s=48&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g" srcset='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/9e0fce9a7b5f7de7f6c528f448007f08?s=96&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-48 photo' height='48' width='48' /></noscript><span itemprop="name">violy</span> <span class="says">says</span>            </p>

            <p class="comment-meta">
                <time class="comment-time" datetime="2012-01-09T04:42:00+00:00" itemprop="commentTime"><a href="http://blogbasics.com/examples-of-blogs/#comment-261" class="comment-time-link" itemprop="url">January 9, 2012 at 4:42 am</a></time>            </p>
        </header>

        <div class="comment-content" itemprop="commentText">

            <p>Hi sir thank you so much for the nice compliment about my blog (Vivi&#8217;s Random Ramblings&#8221;), I&#8217;m blogging for not even 2 months now and it&#8217;s really overwhelming to see this compliment and getting a lot of good feedback Â too and traffic which is a realÂ surpriseÂ .. thank you so much!! &#8211; violy</p>
        </div>

        <div class="comment-reply"><a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='#comment-261' onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "comment-261", "261", "respond", "2334" )' aria-label='Reply to violy'>Reply</a></div>

    </article>
    <ul class="children">

    <li class="comment odd alt depth-2" id="comment-262">
    <article itemprop="comment" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/UserComments">


        <header class="comment-header">
            <p class="comment-author" itemprop="creator" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
                <img alt='' src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" data-src="http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/4383ac0510061b683651a0eca3d58e42?s=48&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g" srcset='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/4383ac0510061b683651a0eca3d58e42?s=96&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-48 photo' height='48' width='48' /><noscript><img alt='' src="http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/4383ac0510061b683651a0eca3d58e42?s=48&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g" srcset='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/4383ac0510061b683651a0eca3d58e42?s=96&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-48 photo' height='48' width='48' /></noscript><span itemprop="name"><a href="http://blogbasics.com" class="comment-author-link" rel="external nofollow" itemprop="url">Paul Odtaa</a></span> <span class="says">says</span>            </p>

            <p class="comment-meta">
                <time class="comment-time" datetime="2012-01-09T09:44:00+00:00" itemprop="commentTime"><a href="http://blogbasics.com/examples-of-blogs/#comment-262" class="comment-time-link" itemprop="url">January 9, 2012 at 9:44 am</a></time>            </p>
        </header>

        <div class="comment-content" itemprop="commentText">

            <p>Hi Violy,Â </p>
<p>I really like your blog and your photography is great.Â </p>
        </div>

        <div class="comment-reply"><a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='#comment-262' onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "comment-262", "262", "respond", "2334" )' aria-label='Reply to Paul Odtaa'>Reply</a></div>

    </article>
    </li><!-- #comment-## -->
</ul><!-- .children -->
</li><!-- #comment-## -->

    <li class="comment even thread-odd thread-alt depth-1" id="comment-270">
    <article itemprop="comment" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/UserComments">


        <header class="comment-header">
            <p class="comment-author" itemprop="creator" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
                <img alt='' src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" data-src="http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/ad28f49a806d0e3abd1a94013a259b9b?s=48&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g" srcset='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/ad28f49a806d0e3abd1a94013a259b9b?s=96&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-48 photo' height='48' width='48' /><noscript><img alt='' src="http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/ad28f49a806d0e3abd1a94013a259b9b?s=48&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g" srcset='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/ad28f49a806d0e3abd1a94013a259b9b?s=96&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-48 photo' height='48' width='48' /></noscript><span itemprop="name"><a href="http://allisondduncan.com" class="comment-author-link" rel="external nofollow" itemprop="url">Allison Duncan</a></span> <span class="says">says</span>            </p>

            <p class="comment-meta">
                <time class="comment-time" datetime="2012-01-20T21:17:00+00:00" itemprop="commentTime"><a href="http://blogbasics.com/examples-of-blogs/#comment-270" class="comment-time-link" itemprop="url">January 20, 2012 at 9:17 pm</a></time>           </p>
        </header>

        <div class="comment-content" itemprop="commentText">

            <p>Hi there,</p>
<p>Thanks for featuring my blog on your site. It&#8217;s always nice to see your work being appreciated and linked to.</p>
<p>I look forward to seeing what your site has coming down the pike.</p>
<p>Thanks for reading!</p>
<p>Allison</p>
        </div>

        <div class="comment-reply"><a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='#comment-270' onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "comment-270", "270", "respond", "2334" )' aria-label='Reply to Allison Duncan'>Reply</a></div>

    </article>
    </li><!-- #comment-## -->
```

I am using jsoup library for parsing HTML and extracting it. I am trying using below code:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://blogbasics.com/examples-of-blogs/").get();

            Elements links = doc.select("itemtype > [itemprop]");

            for (Element element : links) {
                System.out.println(" itemprop :"+element.attr("itemprop"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But am getting empty values. Am new to this work kindly let me know correct code. If anyother way to extract `itemtype` and `itemprop` from HTML please share it will be great help.

```html
<div class="content-sidebar-wrap">
<main class="content" role="main" itemprop="mainContentOfPage" itemscope="itemscope" 
itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog"><article class="post-2334 post type-post status-publish 
format-standard has-post-thumbnail category-blog-basics entry" itemscope="itemscope" 
itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" itemprop="blogPost"><header class="entry-header">
<h1 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">Examples of Blogs</h1> 
<p class="entry-meta">by <span class="entry-author" itemprop="author" itemscope="itemscope" 
itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span class="entry-author-name" itemprop="name">Kenneth Byrd</span></span> |
 Go from 0 to 5,000 blog subscribers in 60 days
 <a href="https://curlcentric.leadpages.net/leadbox/14581e773f72a2%3A12e927026b46dc/5758142528880640/" rel="nofollow">(Click Here)</a>
 </p></header><img src="http://blogbasics.com/wp-content/uploads/Examples-of-Blogs.jpg" width="5315" height="3543" 
 alt="examples of blogs" title="" class="attachment-tru-post wp-post-image" /><div class="entry-content"
 itemprop="text"><h3>Overview</h3><p>This article includes examples of blogs
 from various niches. There are millions of example blogs out there in all 
 different shapes and sizes. A good place to start is 
 </p>
```

expected output

```
itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">
itemprop="mainContentOfPage"

itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" 
itemprop="blogPost"

itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"
itemprop="author"
itemprop="name">
itemprop="text"
```

Comment: why my code doesn't work is <main class="content" role="main" itemprop="mainContentOfPage" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog"> is not inside of a itemtype both itemtype and itemprop exist in same node not inside .i'm not good at jsoup i will delete the answer .someone will help you

Comment: Thanks alot Fast Snail for ur help.

Comment: your question contains tons of content that seems irrelevant. It would increase chances to get a response if you would condense the HTML you try to parse to a minimal example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you really want, but it seems that you need to get all elements containing an attribute `itemtype` together with an attribute `itemprop` or elements that contain only `itemprop` but are direct children of elements that contain `itemtype`. If this is the case, then you can use this:

```
String html = ""
        +"<div class=\"content-sidebar-wrap\">"
        +"<main class=\"content\" role=\"main\" itemprop=\"mainContentOfPage\" itemscope=\"itemscope\" "
        +"itemtype=\"http://schema.org/Blog\"><article class=\"post-2334 post type-post status-publish "
        +"format-standard has-post-thumbnail category-blog-basics entry\" itemscope=\"itemscope\" "
        +"itemtype=\"http://schema.org/BlogPosting\" itemprop=\"blogPost\"><header class=\"entry-header\">"
        +"<h1 class=\"entry-title\" itemprop=\"headline\">Examples of Blogs</h1> "
        +"<p class=\"entry-meta\">by <span class=\"entry-author\" itemprop=\"author\" itemscope=\"itemscope\" "
        +"itemtype=\"http://schema.org/Person\"><span class=\"entry-author-name\" itemprop=\"name\">Kenneth Byrd</span></span> |"
        +" Go from 0 to 5,000 blog subscribers in 60 days"
        +" <a href=\"https://curlcentric.leadpages.net/leadbox/14581e773f72a2%3A12e927026b46dc/5758142528880640/\" rel=\"nofollow\">(Click Here)</a>"
        +" </p></header><img src=\"http://blogbasics.com/wp-content/uploads/Examples-of-Blogs.jpg\" width=\"5315\" height=\"3543\" "
        +" alt=\"examples of blogs\" title=\"\" class=\"attachment-tru-post wp-post-image\" /><div class=\"entry-content\""
        +" itemprop=\"text\"><h3>Overview</h3><p>This article includes examples of blogs"
        +" from various niches. There are millions of example blogs out there in all "
        +" different shapes and sizes. A good place to start is "
        +" </p>"
        ;

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html,"");

Elements els = doc.select("*[itemtype][itemprop], *[itemtype] > *[itemprop]");
for (Element el:els){

    System.out.print(el.attr("itemtype").isEmpty()?"":("\n" +el.attr("itemtype")+"\n"));
    System.out.println(el.attr("itemprop"));
}
```

The important part is the  [JSoup CSS selector](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) `*[itemtype][itemprop], *[itemtype] > *[itemprop]` which has two parts:

1. `*[itemtype][itemprop]` selects elements with both attributes.
2. `*[itemtype] > *[itemprop]` selects elements with attribute `itemprop` that are direct children of elements with attribute  `itemtype`. If you want to allow all children, not only direct ones then just leave out the `>`.

The comma between the selectors works as "OR", so all elements that match any of the listed selectors will be returned.

Comment: Exactly am looking for the same. Actually am trying to extarcting Schema.org microdata metdata's from html so i need itemtype and corresponding itemprop based on that am trying to parse the content of itemprop. Its like key value pair. example like this formate  itemtype [ itemprop:value ]. Finally i could able to get all itemtype and corresponding itemprop from your code really great thanks.